# Ubuntu starts in terminal mode

Tags: desktop-environments, display-manager

I recently installed KDE plasma in Ubuntu but then uninstalled along with all its packages using code `sudo apt autoremove`. 
Now when I start Ubuntu, it opens in terminal mode instead of regular desktop environment.

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution myself after a little bit of research. Turns out the display manager was removed somehow. So I just logged in and installed lightdm using `sudo apt-get install lightdm` and everything was back to normal.